# Only display certain fields based on Opportunity Stage?

Tags: opportunity, record-type

We have a use case where we wanted to display certain fields based on the Opportunity stage. As the opportunity progresses through its lifecycle, more and more fields will be required.

Has anyone encountered a requirement like this before?

I was thinking of changing the recordtype on the fly (through a process builder) as the stage was updated and therefore a new page layout would be referenced. I'm just not sure if this is an ideal solution.

Thanks

Comment: Is separating your fields into sections, and displaying them all an option here? Keeping your fields separated (and all visible) on a layout would be a lot less work than what you're suggesting. Other than that, are you using Classic, or LEX? Planning to change any time soon?

Comment: Yes, we did not want to go with that route. We only wanted to prompt the business for data when they absolutely needed to enter it making for a shorter form. We are on LEX. We could always go the custom route and integrate the logic into an LWC component, but I didn't know if there was a declarative solution out there.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to create a [Path](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=path_overview.htm&type=5). In Setup, you can create a Path, which guides users through the various stages. You can specify multiple fields per stage, and an optional guidance section for custom instructions. All of this is standard functionality you can do with clicks.

Comment: Just to add to @sfdcfox answer, remove the fields you want to display in certain conditions from the layout, keep them only on the Path.